# Matching exact words with stri_replace_all_fixed

Tags: regex, r, stringr

Hi: how do I get R to replace "no" with "not" but not replace "not" with "nott"

The code below works very well with my current dictionaries but not with another dictionary that is replacing negated words with some standardized words.

```
#patterns
replace<-('no')
#replacements
with<-c('not')
#data frame
neg<-data.frame(replace=replace, with=with)
#text to modify
out<-c('not acceptable no good')
#current code
stri_replace_all_fixed(out, neg$replace, neg$with, vectorize_all=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a regex that will match `no` as a whole word:

```
> replace<-('\\bno\\b')  ## <= \b is a word boundary
> with<-c('not')
> neg<-data.frame(replace=replace, with=with)
> out<-c('not acceptable no good')
> stri_replace_all_regex(out, neg$replace, neg$with, vectorize_all=FALSE)
[1] "not acceptable not good"
```

Comment: Do I need to be worried about the whitespace surrounding "no" in the text? Or does the word boundary account for that?

Comment: Word boundaries are zero-width assertions that do not consume text, there should be no issues with  whitespace.

Comment: Yes it did! Sorry, this is a very low priority project for me, so it slipped by me!